# 404 pages on magento admin and subpages

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, http-status-code-404, virtualbox, turnkeylinux.org

I am working on a Magento page then after a while I couldn't access my admin anymore

```
Not Found
The requested URL /magento/chkbackoffice_admin was not found on this server.
```

also other subpages except for the homepage are inaccessible as well. The site's location is on my VirtualBox's TurnkeyLinux.

I have already restarted the appliance but still same error. Also copied the original directory of the codebase to replace the current site but same error persists. What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please put config.xml of custom extension

Comment: @vishnu add index.php before admin path

eg: `localhost/magento/index.php/chkbackoffice_admin`

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR yea that do the trick but how about other pages of the site? Still a 404 for them.

Comment: @AmitBera the config.xml file has too many lines. Can't find a way to display it properly here. Sorry

Comment: @vishnu once you logi into the admin panel

Go to `syayem->configuration->general->web->search Engine optimazation` Set as no then check other pages 'll load properly

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR yes it worked. It displayed some pages. But do you have any clues why it happened? I was previously able to access it but when I put my laptop to sleep, it is not accessible anymore